# Label StringFormat doesn't work

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to format a {datetime?} property with stringFormat, but I don't know why it doesn't applied to.

this is my code

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="{Binding From, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the contents of the label into a TextBlock

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=From, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"/>
</Label>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that 1) it's cumbersome, more work than necessary, and 2) it removes access text support.  You can instead use AccessText instead of TextBlock to retain the latter function at least.

Comment: Can anyone expand on why it works on just TextBlocks? After all it's a data-binding feature.