# Why is StringFormat being ignored in this Xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I have a simple Label that I want to display some diagnostic data with a label "header" built-in. Rather than use 2 labels in a horizontal StackPanel, I figured I'd try using `{Binding StringFormat}`. Here's the XAML:

```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeData, StringFormat=Value: {0}}" />
   </StackPanel>
```

In this case `SomeData` is a string property on the view-model and it is correctly bound to the view. The value of `SomeData` is "ABC".

I would expect the Label to display: "Value: ABC"
It's not. It's displaying simply: "ABC"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why `StringFormat` doesn't work, I guess it just doesn't fit property other than `Text`. For `Content` property, you can try `ContentStringFormat` instead :

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeData}" ContentStringFormat="Value: {0}" />
```

Some people suggested to wrap `Content` with `TextBlock` and use `StringFormat` within `TextBlock's Text` property  binding [f.e [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068030/label-stringformat-doesnt-work), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498649/wpf-binding-stringformat-not-formatting)].

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeData, StringFormat='{}Value: {0}'}"/>
</Label>
```

Comment: Marking this one as the answer since it includes a reference to other related questions and includes code snippets.

Comment: hmm.. I can't see a reason why many insist to use StringFormat with TextBlock instead of using ContentStringFormat. The latter looks simpler to me.

Answer (score 5):

`StringFormat` works on properties of type `string` (when the object you are binding to is being converted to a string the string format is applied).

The `Content` property of `Label` is of type Object.

Suggested solution: Use `TextBlock` instead!

Comment: Always seemed bizarre to me that it doesn't just use the stringformat if _you have explicitly set it_. Weird Microsoft, really weird.